# Unable retrieve same double value which was interted into mysql

Tags: mysql, database, decimal

I have to store decimal value into database (mysql). Requirement is to retrieve same value which was inserted irrespective of any insignificant digits present after decimal in original number. For example if 2.5 was inserted then select should retrieve 2.5 if 2.50 is inserted then 2.50 should be retrieve. I found that I am using double data type then 2.50 is retrieved as 2.5 removing 0 which insignificant. I use Decimal datatype then 0 is padded depending upon precision present in decimal declaration.
For example if Decimal(3,2) is used for creating table then 2.5 and 2.50 both is retrieved as 2.50
Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing an int to SQL, but keep leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309114/storing-an-int-to-sql-but-keep-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve the value in the select statement you have to cast the value in the fitting format, like that:

```
SELECT CAST(2.50 AS DECIMAL(3,2));
SELECT CAST(2.50 AS DOUBLE);
```

Comment: With this approach it is assumed each number in column is having decimal precision. But in my case number may have different precision. For example inserted value can 23, 2.35, 2.30, 2.5 etc retrieved values should be same