# Store integer with leading 0 (if set)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

using eloquent is it possible to save a numeric value like `012345` with the leading `0` or is the only possibility to store the value as string?

To provide more details: I'd like to store a zip-code, which can have a leading `0` in Germany. There's no possibility to always add the `0`, because not all zips start with `0`

Comment: you can add DEFAULT constraint in your table field

Answer (score 1):

> Numeric datatypes do not retain leading zeros, as they are insignificant to the number you want to store. Char or Varchar is more appropriate. You could set a constraint to ensure only numeric characters are stored.

> If you absolutely cannot change the data type, then another alternative is to store the number of leading zeros into another int field

> So in your example you would store:
> Value : 32
> Leading zeros : 2

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/23309167/5442966

Answer (score 1):

`012345`  is not a number. It's a string. `12345`  is the number. SQL Server is able to recognize that those extra zeros are not needed to define the number, so it ignores them. If you want to dispaly a value as `012345`  to the application, I'd suggest doing the formatting on the application side. That way the number stored in SQL Server is still a number if you want do addition, aggregation, or other calculations. If you really have to store it as `012345`, you need to convert it to a character field; char, varchar, nvarchar, nchar.

[For Details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-do-i-preserve-the-leading-zeros-when-i-insert-a-number-into-this-table/15054)